# Sending image as a Stream (Android)

Tags: c#, android, rest

I have a REST service set up to receive a Stream of Data to save it as an image.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UpImage/{path}")]
    void UpImage(string path, Stream filecontents);

public void UpImage(string path, Stream filecontents)
    {
        Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(filecontents);
        img.Save(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/attachments/test/") + "SrvTest.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

I would like to do the process through an AsyncTask on android to connect to the service and collect its response.

My problem is i am not sure how to send the image as a stream, i see a lot of information sending them as Byte Arrays.
Is this possible and if so How?